# Playwright: How to pass environment variables from library to pipeline?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure, integration-testing, playwright

### Background

I have a React/TypeScript project running Playwright integration tests in an Azure DevOps pipeline. The pipeline gets environment variables from an Azure DevOps library.

### Problem

I can run the tests locally against my deployed pre-prod environment successfully.

However, the tests fail in the pipeline. They fail because the pipeline cannot read the environment variables I am trying to pass in from the library.

Failing line of code:

```
await page.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'myVariable' }).fill(process.env.MyVariable as string);
```

Pipeline error on my environment variable:
[image: locator.fill: value: expected string, got undefined]

**How do I pass environment variables from the library to the pipeline such that Playwright can read them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

1. I updated my test file name from `myFile.spec.ts` to `myFile.spec.tsx`.
2. I prefixed my environment variables with `REACT_APP_`.

```
await page.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'myVariable' }).fill(process.env.REACT_APP_MY_VARIABLE as string);
```

3. Now my Azure DevOps pipeline can read the variables in the Azure DevOps library, and the tests succeed!

[image: Running 3 tests using 1 worker. 3 passed]